# customize bollon message of textmode properties TextBox in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.net 4.5 `TextBox` has a `TextMode` properties and we can use values such `Number`, `Date`, ...

When I set the `TextMode` value to `Number`, and run the program, if user enters an invalid character and presses submit button, a bollon message appears in `TextBox` and the content is

> Please enter a number.

Now I want to customize this message. (Not ToolTip)

Comment: Why dont you use custom validators .. ?

Comment: beacuse i don'n . i want use this . can you help me ?

Comment: Now we cannot edit balloon message of textmode . If you want customize message, you have to use validators .